# Django regular expression for active menu item

Tags: django

I have a custom template tag function for highlighting menu item, like :

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def is_active(context, pattern):
    request = context['request']
    path = request.path
    import re
    if re.search(pattern, request.path):
        return 'active'
    return ''
```

And in the template  i write

```
#this regex is not giving the correct result
{% is_active 'artists|artist\w+$' %}
```

for 'artists' link to highlight.

---> /en/artist/markoxxxx/1  --- it works for this url 
---> /en/festival/2012/05/07/testes/artists  --- it does not work for this url

Comment: ok. {% is_active 'artists|artist.*$' %} is working. But is there a better way of writing?

Answer (score 0):

```
if re.match('^/en/artists', request.path):
        return 'active'
```

^ means start of string